# Testing environment update to v23 Business Central

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

I did schedule the Business Central update to v23.2 but it automatically gets cancelled and rescheduled to 7 days later, I guess it isn't ready to update but I can't see any feedback directly in BC without asking to the final user to check the email inbox

This is the automated email that is sent to an admin when the update is rescheduled:
[image]

Is there a way to test the environment to the update and get the reasons why it's not possible to update directly on BC or add another email so all administrators can recieve the same email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several testing, as @ChristianBraeunlich said you can schedule updates manually from the Admin Center in the Environment section

To solve my question, you can add multiple recipients of the update results in the Admin Center in the Notification Recipients tab.

All email accounts registered in Notification Recipients will get an email with the update results.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to test the environment to the update [...]

This is scheduled whenever an update is available. If I'm not mistaken an administrator can also manually perform updates to environments.

> [...] and get the reasons why it's not possible to update directly on BC [...]

The reason in this case is the code in the custom report object **AdjustExchangeRatesSCDEKA.Report.al**: "src/report/AdjustExchangeRatesSCDEKA.Report.al (1404,22) - Error AL0126: No overload for method 'GetDefaultDimID' takes 7 arguments.

```
Method 'GetDefaultDimID' is marked for removal.
Reason: Replaced by procedures GetDefaultDimID() with DefaultDimSource: List of [Dictionary of [Integer, Code[20]]]. Tag: 20.0. AL(AL0432)
```

I recommend to update the custom solution **SCDEKA** first to the latest version. If this does not resolve the issue, you, your partner or the 3rd party company would have to resolve this issue by replacing the **TableID: array[10] of Integer** and **No: array[10] of Code[20]** parameters by **DefaultDimSource: List of [Dictionary of [Integer, Code[20]]]**.

> [...] or add another email so all administrators can recieve the same email?

I don't know if it's possible to add multiple E-Mail accounts. Maybe it is possible to forward these E-Mails to a mailing list.

If you are missing a feature, please create an idea on [aka.ms/bcideas](https://aka.ms/bcideas).